# Get countries with more than a 50% of Roman Catholic poblation

Tags: xml, http, xslt

I'm using cooktop and I want to get a la list of countries that have more than a 50 percent of Roman Catholic poblation. 
I've tried the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="mondial">
            <xsl:for-each select="country">
            <xsl:sort select="name"/>

            <xsl:if test="contains(religions,'Roman Catholic')">
                <xsl:if test="religions[@percentage &gt; 50]">
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="religions"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="religions/@percentage"/>%
                        </li>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that I'm getting some countries that have less than a 50%.
xml extract from where I'm getting this problem:

```
<mondial>
<country id='f0_772' 
     name='British Virgin Islands'
     capital='f0_1852'
     population='13195'
     datacode='VI'
     total_area='150'
     population_growth='1.29'
     infant_mortality='19.16'
     gdp_total='133'
     inflation='2.5'
     government='dependent territory of the UK'>
     <name >
       British Virgin Islands
     </name>
     <city id='f0_1852' 
       country='f0_772'>
       <name >
         Road Town
       </name>
     </city>
     <ethnicgroups  percentage='100'>
       Asian
     </ethnicgroups>
     <religions  percentage='6'>
       Roman Catholic
     </religions>
     <religions  percentage='86'>
       Protestant
     </religions>
     <languages  percentage='100'>
       English
     </languages>
     <encompassed 
       continent='f0_126'
       percentage='100'/>
   </country>
</mondial>
```

I think my mistake is that I'm looking if one of the religions have more than a 50% but not taking especifically the Roman Catholic one. If I'm right how can I solve this? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have two `xsl:if` conditions...

```
<xsl:if test="contains(religions,'Roman Catholic')">
      <xsl:if test="religions[@percentage &gt; 50]">
```

The first is checking, for the current country, if they have a Roman Catholic regligion (so, for your example, that is true)

The second condition then checks if there is a religion that has a percentage greater than 50. It is not checking that the religion is Roman Catholic. The two if conditions are checked separately.

You need to combine the two conditions into one

```
<xsl:if test="religions[contains(.,'Roman Catholic')][@percentage &gt; 50]">
     ....
</xsl:if>
```

Note that, you may still have an issue with displaying the religion, as this line will only display the first religion.

```
<xsl:value-of select="religions"/>
```

It might be better if you move the test on religions into the `xsl:for-each` instead

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="country[religions[contains(.,'Roman Catholic') and @percentage &gt; 50]]">
    <xsl:sort select="name"/>
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="religions" select="religions[contains(.,'Roman Catholic')]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$religions"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$religions/@percentage"/>%
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Tahnks, I've tried with this code too but I don't know if it could be useful too. `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="mondial/country">
  <xsl:sort select="name"/>
   <xsl:if test="contains(religions[@percentage&gt;50],'Roman Catholic')">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`